# Pie Chart does not update after first click? onClick works only for first time

Tags: javascript, dom, d3.js, nvd3.js

Here is the plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/qJnZzBS4ZOUtD2q9FV11?p=preview

**Problem**

When you first click on the slice, you see another pie to appear, but if you click second time nothing happens

The event binding seems to work just for the first time

The relevant code to bind event in plunker is at `Line 143` and labelled below

```
d3.selectAll('.nv-slice')
  .on('click', function(){
    if (where === '#pie1') {
      var parentCategory = this.getElementsByClassName("nv-label")[0].textContent;
      $scope.visualizePie2(parentCategory);
    }
  });
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some struggle and refactoring, this is working now

The demo and code is http://plnkr.co/edit/qJnZzBS4ZOUtD2q9FV11?p=preview